# Google ARcore surface detection on samsung galaxy note 8

Tags: android, arcore, samsung-galaxy

I'm currently making an application using google ARcore. 
I have 2 test devices. LG Q6, Samsung Galaxy Note 8.

The application works perfectly on LG Q6 but, the Note 8's speed of the surface detection is horribly slow.

I don't know why it happens, I guess it's caused by the rear camera's calibration setting or something.

Do you have any ideas about it? 
please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the device issue of my note 8
Other note 8s worked fine. silly :(

Comment: We’re you able to isolate what it was about your device that caused this to be slower than other devices?

Comment: @Jeremy Caney I couldn't find the exact cause for the issue. but after trying test-run on 3 other note 8s, mine was the only one which had the slow speed.